# Bosh Concourse error when trying to add external workers | failed to configure SSH server: ssh: no key found

Tags: worker, concourse, cf-bosh

We are having a hard time setting up the cluster for an external worker. I think we don't understand all of the SSH keys that need to be created manually and exchanged. The TSA job errors with

`failed to configure SSH server: ssh: no key found`.

here is my manifest for bosh:

```
---
name: concourse

releases:
- name: concourse
  version: latest
- name: garden-runc
  version: latest

stemcells:
- alias: trusty
  os: ubuntu-trusty
  version: latest

instance_groups:
- name: web
  instances: 1
  vm_type: default
  stemcell: trusty
  azs: [z1]
  networks: [{name: default}]
  jobs:
  - name: atc
    release: concourse
    properties:
      no_really_i_dont_want_any_auth: true
      postgresql_database: &atc_db atc
  - name: tsa
    release: concourse
    properties:
      host_key: ((tsa_host_private_key))
      host_public_key: ((tsa_host_public_key))
      authorized_keys:
      - ((osx_worker_public_key))

- name: db
  instances: 1
  vm_type: default
  stemcell: trusty
  persistent_disk_type: default
  azs: [z1]
  networks: [{name: default}]
  jobs:
  - name: postgresql
    release: concourse
    properties:
      databases:
      - name: *atc_db
        role: postgresql
        password: password

- name: worker
  instances: 1
  vm_type: default
  stemcell: trusty
  azs: [z1]
  networks: [{name: default}]
  jobs:
  - name: groundcrew
    release: concourse
    properties:
      tsa:
        host_public_key: ((tsa_host_public_key))
  - name: baggageclaim
    release: concourse
    properties: {}
  - name: garden
    release: garden-runc
    properties:
      garden:
        listen_network: tcp
        listen_address: 0.0.0.0:7777

update:
  canaries: 1
  max_in_flight: 1
  serial: false
  canary_watch_time: 1000-60000
  update_watch_time: 1000-60000
```

Comment: How did you generate the values for "tsa_host_private_key" and "tsa_host_public_key"? Can you double check that the values have been inserted in the generated bosh deployment manifest.

Comment: We generate these values with ssh-keygen and substitute them in using the `bosh interpolate` command. We checked the output and they are populated. @ErginBabani